# Kafka Flux not working in Rest Controller

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, project-reactor

I have the following controller:

```
private final Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> fluxReceiver;

@GetMapping(value = "/events", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getEvents() {
    return fluxReceiver.map(x -> x.value());
}
```

And I declared the bean Flux> like this:

```
@Bean
public Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> fluxReceiver() {
    String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "sample-consumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "sample-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(props);

    ReceiverOptions<String, String> options = receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton(TOPIC));

    return KafkaReceiver.create(options).receive();

}
```

So then, I am able to inject it in the controller, and return it when someone calls to the rest endpoint /events.

I am calling that endpoint using cURL. The thing is that, when I send an event, if I debug it, I can see that the .map method is triggered and I return the value of the event, in this case a String. But, in the cURL console I can't see the event.

However, if I don't use Kafka, and I create a TopicProcessor, then I can see the event in cURL. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I wonder if it's an issue with the Flux not completing? Have you tried to use cUrl in streaming mode with the `--no-buffer` flat?

Comment: I just tried, and now I can see the event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: My knowledge of Kafka is limited.

A Kafka topic is continuous, so a `Flux` representation of a topic doesn't emit `onComplete`. As a consequence, Spring Framework will turn that `Flux` into a streaming response using chunked encoding...

`cUrl` expects a default finite response to come back from the server. It performs a bit of buffering and overall doesn't necessarily writes HTTP chunks on the console *as they arrive*. But in the case of such a streaming response, what you need it to do is to output data immediately as it becomes available.

This can be done with the `--no-buffer` flag of `cUrl`.

Comment: awesome answer!